# Codeigniter dompdf image not rendering

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

I am finding problem in using dompdf with codeigniter, in rendering the image.

Actually my requirement is as follows:

1. User fills a given form.
2. He clicks ab button to print the form.
3. At the same time when he print the form, a pdf version of that
   from is to be sent to user.

I am using dompdf for that. It works well, but the logo which is an image is not displayed in view and also in rendered pdf file.

I googled for that, and found that image path should be wrt server and not wrt application.
eg. my image path is `/var/www/my_system/images/logo.png`.

But it didn't visible. It shows fails to load URL.

I am using dompdf-0.5.2 version.

Please suggest.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Some PNG images can be problematic for 0.5.x. Have you tried a GIF or PNG? What about supplying a web URL, i.e. http://example.com/images/logo.png?

Comment: My image is in PNG format. I have tried weburl also. In that case it shows a big red cross.

Comment: Hey, finally I got soltion myself. But I don't know how it did work. Actually my image was in PNG with size approx 20kb. When I convert it to JPG its size reduces to approx 3kb and it renders successfully. Can anybody explain me the exact image size and other issue .......very thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to be related to the PHP memory limit. You could try increasing the memory limit to prevent issues in the future.

Some image operations can be costly in terms of system memory. dompdf has to do a lot more processing with PNG to support the full feature set. The KB size of the image isn't the determining factor because the memory footprint has more to do with the dimensions of the image.

FYI, it always helps debugging PHP issues to be able to see any errors thrown.